# Join Query in laravel to avoid report abused users

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a join between two tables to avoid report abuse uses in user listing what I'm doing is given below:

What I have 
I've 2 tables which are

users Table

```
id |  name  |  
1  |  testA | 
2  |  testB |
3  |  testC |
4  |  testD |
5  |  testE |
```

report_abuse Table

```
id | reported_by|  reported_to
1  | 1          |  2
2  | 1          |  3
```

now what i need is when I query I should get only 2 records 4 and 5

What I did 
I create a query to fetch the above records which is :

```
DB::table('users as U')
->select('U.id','U.name')
->where('U.id', '!=', auth()->user()->id)
->leftJoin('report_abuse as RA', 'RA.reported_by', '=', 'U.id')
->where('RA.reported_by', '=', auth()->user()->id)
->where('RA.reported_to', '!=', 'U.id')
->orderBy('U.id', 'desc')
->paginate(10);
```

I'm doing something wrong here that's why I'm not getting proper results.

Can you guys please help me out, much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand, you need the list of users exluding the one's he reported and himself.

here's a solution

```
$authId = auth()->user()->id;
DB::table('users as U')
    ->select('U.id','U.name')
    ->where('U.id', '!=', $authId)
    ->leftJoin('report_abuse as RA', function ($report) use ($authId){
        $report->on('reported_to', '=', 'U.id')
            ->where('reported_by', '=', $authId);
    })
    ->whereNull('reported_to')
    ->orderBy('U.id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(10);
```